# How can I display the most recent status update?

Tags: javascript, express, ejs

I'm working on a Facebook clone and I have two views:

- The `index` view which you get redirected to after logging in. This is the page which allows you to make status updates.
- The `profile` view which allows you to view your profile & see all your status updates.

On the `index` view I would also like the user to see all their friends most recent status updates but I'm having trouble implementing that logic. I can't find a way to sort status updates by user and then by most recent update.

Here is my code

`User Schema`

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  username: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: [true, "can't be blank"],
    match: [/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/, "is invalid"],
    index: true,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    lowercase: true,
    unique: true,
    required: [true, "can't be blank"],
    match: [/\S+@\S+\.\S+/, "is invalid"],
    index: true,
  },
  password: String,
  email: String,
  createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  friends: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "User",
    },
  ],
});
```

`Status Schema // where all the status updates are stored`

```
const statusSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  content: { type: String, required: true },
  author: String,
  createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
});
```

`GET for /users/USERNAME`

```
router.get("/:user", function (req, res, next) {
  const user = req.user.username;
  const id = req.params.user;
  Status.find({}, "content author createdAt")
    .sort({ title: 1 })
    .exec(function (err, list_status) {
      if (err) {
        return next(err);
      }
      res.render("profile", { status_list: list_status, user: user, id: id });
    });
});
```

`POST for /users/USERNAME`

```
router.post("/:user", [
  // Validate and sanitize fields.
  body("content", "Content must not be empty.")
    .trim()
    .isLength({ min: 1 })
    .escape(),
  // Process request after validation and sanitization.
  (req, res, next) => {
    // Extract the validation errors from a request.
    const errors = validationResult(req);

    // Create an article object with escaped and trimmed data.
    const status = new Status({
      content: req.body.content,
      author: req.body.author,
    });

    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      // Get all authors and genres for form.
      async.parallel((err, results) => {
        if (err) {
          return next(err);
        }
        res.render("profile", {
          content: content,
          author: author,
          status,
          errors: errors.array(),
        });
      });
      return;
    }

    // Data from form is valid. Save article.
    status.save((err) => {
      if (err) {
        return next(err);
      }
      res.redirect("/");
    });
  },
]);
```